# Python ThreadPoolExecutor stopped executing

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I have following code that use ThreadPoolExecutor to get request to url and **scrape** some data. I put a counter to watch the progress.

```
result = {}  
counter = 0
def scrap_data(url) -> str:
    description = extract_description(url)
    return description


df = pd.read_csv('jivo_domains.csv')
url_list = df['url'].tolist()[2000:3000]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(scrap_data, url): url for url in url_list}
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        url = futures[future]
        result[url] = future.result()

dump_data(result)
```

By reaching 998 it stopped and i don't know why. How to prevent tread to dead or probably it's deadlock ? The extract_description function:

```
from trafilatura import fetch_url, extract
def extract_description(url: str) -> str:
    file_content = fetch_url(url)  # html страница, как строка
    return (extract(file_content) or "").replace('\n', "")  # убираем trailing newline
```

Comment: What does extract_description do? Also, since Python 3.7 you could reliably use the threading module. See:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: extract_description sent request to url and after scrap some data from this request

Comment: I was rather hoping you'd show the code for extract_description because that's potentially where your problem lies

Comment: @AndyKnight one of my ideas it that some of threads isn't complete

Comment: You might want to review your use-case and consider if you can achieve your objective(s) without trafilatura in case that's where your problem is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235410/discussion-between-andy-knight-and-alex-nikitin).